# How to pattern match JsArray of JsStrings

Tags: scala, spray-json

For instance I have a simple author's JSON:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "articles": [
    "string",
    "string",
    "string"
  ]
}
```

I am defining Json reading format:

```
implicit object authorFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Author] {
  override def write(a: Author) = ???

  override def read(json: JsValue) = json.asJsObject.getFields("name", "articles") match {
    case Seq(JsString(name), JsArray(articles)) => ... //Build author
  }
}
```

This pattern matching guarantees `"articles"` is an array(of `JsValues`). But it is not guarantees `"articles"` is an array of strings. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deserialising `articles` to `List[String]` like so

```
articles.map(_.convertTo[String]).toList
```

if `jsonFormat2` is not an option. Here is a working example

```
import spray.json._
import DefaultJsonProtocol._

object MyApp extends App {
  case class Author(name: String, articles: List[String])

  implicit object authorFormat extends RootJsonFormat[Author] {
    override def write(a: Author) = ???

    override def read(json: JsValue) = json.asJsObject.getFields("name", "articles") match {
      case Seq(JsString(name), JsArray(articles)) => Author(name, articles.map(_.convertTo[String]).toList)
    }
  }

  val raw =
    """
      |{
      |  "name": "string",
      |  "articles": [
      |    "string,
      |    "string",
      |    "string"
      |  ]
      |}
    """.stripMargin



  val json = raw.parseJson
  val author = json.convertTo[Author]
  println(author)
}
```

which outputs

```
Author(string,List(string, string, string))
```

whilst if `articles` contains a non-string like so

```
  val raw =
    """
      |{
      |  "name": "string",
      |  "articles": [
      |    1,
      |    "string",
      |    "string"
      |  ]
      |}
    """.stripMargin
```

we get error

```
Exception in thread "main" spray.json.DeserializationException: Expected String as JsString, but got 1
```

Comment: Infortunatelly, I can not provide the autoformat `jsonFormat2(Author)`, as reality is more complex unlike my example. In a few words: I am extending old api's entity with new field. Just writing `jsonFormat2(Author)` brokes a backward compatibility for this entity.